# How to build/run one Dockerfile per build job in Travis-CI?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I've got a repository with multiple Dockerfiles which take ~20min each to build: https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/pyside2-wheels

I'd like to efficiently divide these Dockerfiles to be built in its own jobs.

Right now, this is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: python

sudo: required
dist: trusty

python:
  - 2.7
  - 3.5

services:
  - docker

install:
  - docker build -f Dockerfile-Ubuntu16.04-py${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION} -t fredrikaverpil/pyside2-ubuntu16.04-py${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION} .
  - docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/pyside-setup/dist fredrikaverpil/pyside2-ubuntu16.04-py${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION}

script:
  - ls -al *.whl /
```

This creates two jobs, one per Python version. However, I'd rather have one job per Dockerfile, as I'm about to add more such files.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it, I think.

```
language: python

sudo: required
dist: trusty

services:
  - docker

matrix:
  include:
    - env: DOCKER_OS=ubuntu16.04
      python: 2.7
    - env: DOCKER_OS=ubuntu16.04
      python: 3.5
    - env: DOCKER_OS=centos7
      python: 2.7

install:
  - docker build -f Dockerfile-$DOCKER_OS-py${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION} -t fredrikaverpil/pyside2-$DOCKER_OS-py${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION} .
  - docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/pyside-setup/dist fredrikaverpil/pyside2-$DOCKER_OS-py${TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION}

script:
  - ls -al *.whl /
```

This results in three job builds.